# iOS 10 UISearchBar height more than iOS 11

Tags: ios, swift, uisearchbar

I have implemented search in table view using `UISearchBar` by adding `UISearchBar` as an object outside table in storyboard. Not using table header.

Search works fine but iOS 10 `UISearchBar` height more than iOS 11. How do i fix it?

Not sure whether this could be the reason but i have height constraint of 44 on `UISearchBar` and I am using scope bar so change height of search bar using below method else scope bar stays below search field.

```
func searchBarShouldBeginEditing(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) -> Bool {

    if searchBar.showsScopeBar == false {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, animations: {

            searchBar.showsScopeBar = true
            self.searchBarHeightConstraint.constant = self.searchBarHeightConstraint.constant  + self.maxHeaderHeight
            searchBar.sizeToFit()
            let scopeBarBackgroundImage = UIImage(color: UIColor.white)
            searchBar.scopeBarBackgroundImage = scopeBarBackgroundImage
            searchBar.setShowsCancelButton(true, animated: true)
        })
    }
    return true
}
```

please see the difference in the image.

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: I see one of your simulators is an iPhone 6 while the other one is an iPhone 8 Plus. Have you tried comparing the same phone sizes?

Comment: checked 6 plus. it shows same height issue as iPhone 6. I checked iPhone 6 Plus with iOS 11.3. Is search field height less in iOS 10.3?